# Использование условий выбора переменных

Tags: php

Есть HTML страница, с которой при помощи AJAX методом POST серверу отправляются данные фруктов.

На стороне PHP я эти данные принимаю:

```
$banana = $_POST['banana'];  // 2 штуки
$apple = $_POST['apple'];  // 5 штук
$orange = $_POST['orange'];  // 3 штуки
```

В зависимости от наличия переменных я должен вывести текст:

```
if (isset($banana)) {
    echo '2 банана';
}
if (isset($banana) && isset($apple)) {
    echo '2 банана и 5 яблок';
}
if (isset($banana) && isset($apple) && isset($orange)) {
    echo '2 банана, 5 яблок и 3 апельсина';
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что наличии всех трёх переменных поочередно выводятся все 3 условия, вместо одного нужного:

'2  банана2  банана и 5 яблок2  банана, 5 яблок и 3 апельсина'.

Понятно почему: все 3 переменные существуют.

Мне нужно, чтобы при наличии одновременно всех 3-х переменных выводилось только одно условие, а не три сразу, т.е чтобы было:

```
 echo '2 банана, 5 яблок и 3 апельсина';
```

При наличии одновременно 2-х переменных тоже одно условие, без вышестоящего, а именно:

```
 echo '2 банана и 5 яблок';
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Решения все рабочие, все одинаково хороши... просто одинаковы... но у всех есть недостаток -- плохо масштабируются. Хардкод. А если будет 4 фрукта -- так и будете бегать код править? Пять? Шесть? Хороший вариант никто не озвучил (правда, не факт, что он и нужен топикстартеру), когда строка "X something, Y another, ..... and Z last" формируется на основе анализа массива, а потом уже выводится.

Comment: @AK, это так, конечно, но спросили конкретно - ответили так же. Мы же не можем додумывать - а вот тут заюзаем шаблоны, так, значит подтянем `Twig`, хм, а массив может ещё по `GET`, передаваться на разные маршруты, подтянем роутер из пака `Symfony` (а на всякий пожарный весь пакет).

Comment: @Other ...и просклонять существительные в зависимости от количества. Ну да, поэтому я просто поворчал немного в комментах и всё. Пусть останется намёком на будущее топикстартеру или кто будет читать вопрос.

Comment: @AK, поворчать в комментах... Что может быть лучше? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `elseif` condition.

**Важно**: Нужно проверять от самых специфичных запросов до самого общего (от комбинаций из трёх, до проверки одного):

```
$banana = true;//$_POST['banana'];  // 2 штуки
$apple = true;//$_POST['apple'];  // 5 штук
$orange = true;//$_POST['orange'];  // 3 штуки

if(isset($banana) && isset($apple) && isset($orange)){
    echo '2 банана, 5 яблок и 3 апельсина';
}elseif(isset($banana) && isset($apple)){
    echo '2 банана и 5 яблок';
}elseif(isset($banana)){
    echo '2 банана';
}
```

https://repl.it/Calu/0

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, нужно переставить их местами и использовать `elseif`:

```
if (isset($banana) && isset($apple) && isset($orange)) {
    echo '2 банана, 5 яблок и 3 апельсина';
}
elseif (isset($banana) && isset($apple)) {
    echo '2 банана и 5 яблок';
}
elseif (isset($banana)) {
    echo '2 банана';
}
```

чтобы последующие условия проверялись, только если предыдущие неверны.